# Sublime Text Editor with '+' sign on the left side

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Why there are plus signs on the left side of my sublime text 3 text editor on every line? How to remove it?

[image]

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SyntaxFold

Comment: do i need to install that package?

Comment: Dunno, I've switched to first Atom and now Visual Studio Code. What happens when you click on the `+`?

Comment: I've found the reason why. It's because of git. If i remove git from the folder, the plus sign disappear. But the thing is, I need to use it with git, but I hate the plus sign..

Answer (score 1):

You have probably installed the [GitGutter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GitGutter) package. It highlights additions to your code with a `+` symbol, removal with a `-` symbol and changes with a circle.

If you don't like this feature, you can either disable (or uninstall) the entire package or use the *GitGutter: Disable for View* command to disable the markers for the current document.

If you don't like the appearance of those markers, you can change the styles by running the *Preferences: GitGutter Popup Stylesheet* command and edit the styles.